# Type 'T' cannot be used to index type 'RowType'

Tags: typescript

I have this basically:

```
type RowType = {
  fooLow: number;
  fooMid: number;
  fooHigh: number;
  barLow: string;
  barMid: string;
  barHigh: string;
}

type ErrorType = {
  fooLow?: boolean;
  fooMid?: boolean;
  fooHigh?: boolean;
  barLow?: boolean;
  barMid?: boolean;
  barHigh?: boolean;
}

type NumberKeyType = 'fooLow' | 'fooMid' | 'fooHigh';
type StringKeyType = 'barLow' | 'barMid' | 'barHigh';
```

Then I use it like this:

```
const row = {
  fooLow: 1;
  fooMid: 2;
  fooHigh: 3;
  barLow: 'hello';
  barMid: 'world';
  barHigh: 'asdf';
}

check<NumberKeyType>(row, 'fooLow', 'fooMid', 'fooHigh')
check<StringKeyType>(row, 'barLow', 'barMid', 'barHigh')

function check<T>(
  rowData: RowType,
  low: T,
  middle: T,
  high: T
): ErrorType {
  const newError: ErrorType = {};
  if (
    rowData[low] ||
    rowData[middle] ||
    rowData[high]
  ) {
    let isMissing = false;
    if (!rowData[low]) {
      isMissing = true;
      newError[low] = true;
    }
    if (!rowData[middle]) {
      isMissing = true;
      newError[middle] = true;
    }
    if (!rowData[high]) {
      isMissing = true;
      newError[high] = true;
    }

    // don't need to compute relations if any are missing.
    if (isMissing) {
      return newError;
    }
  }

  return newError;
}
```

It is returning the following error:

```
Type 'T' cannot be used to index type 'RowType'
```

What must I do differently to get it to allow for passing in `T`? I would like to use typed generics to make it so my function is more reusable, rather than having 1 function for numbers and a second one for strings (and in my case it's slightly different, I have a few more variations). So I would like to use type generics if possible, not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a constraint or else `T` could be any type:

```
function check<T extends NumberKeyType | StringKeyType>(...) { ... }
```

```
function check<T extends keyof RowType>(...) { ... }
```

Comment: Or `<T extends keyof RowType>`.